# If an employee doesn't show up to work, how long is typical before the company investigates?

Tags: human-resources

(Not sure if this is on-topic)

This is hypothetical and is for the plot of a story I'm thinking about.

If an employee doesn't show up for work, how long is typical before the company investigates? For example if the employee suffers a fall that disables them, how long will it take before they can expect their workplace to summon an ambulance?

I'm only looking for an order of magnitude estimate: hours? One day? Two days? A week? A description of the typical protocol if this happens will also be helpful.

Tagging this with human resources because I imagine if anyone at the workplace investigates, it's HR.

Comment: In your hypothetical, does the fall happen at work (or a work site) or outside of work?

Comment: @BSMP outside of work (hence they don't show up to work).

Comment: OK, well the first thing is that they wouldn't send an ambulance because they don't know that you're injured. They might do a wellness check if they haven't been able to contact you though. You might be able to get more specific answers if you can tell use the location and industry this person is in, the nature of their work, and how high up/important they are in the workplace.

Comment: @BSMP The employee is disabled enough that they can't call for an ambulance themselves, so the response would first have to establish that the employee is injured and then only summon an ambulance. If a wellness check does that then it'd be suitable. The location/industry, their seniority, etc. are free parameters of the story. If those things affect the response time (by how much?) I can configure those to get the response time that I want.

Comment: Every job I've ever had, in the US, has asked for emergency contact numbers.  I don't know that I've ever seen any official policy that says to call it after a certain amount of time.  If I were this person's manager and they went missing without any contact for a couple of days, I'd probably try to get in touch with their emergency contact to check on them.

Comment: One of my wife's co-workers recently passed away. They lived alone and while doing some work on their house on the weekend fell off the ladder, hitting their head. Monday they did not show up to work. Tuesday another co-worker/friend went over to their house and found them unconscious on the garage floor. They did not make it...

Comment: @JonCuster sounds like an answer.

Comment: Ironically this got flagged in my newsfeed today :D https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-60312231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Companies will in general not call emergency service unless there a strong indicators (with supporting hard data) that something is really off. This would be rare.
2. Manager or HR will first try to contact the employee by phone or message.
3. If there is no reply after more than a day, they might try to contact the emergency contact of the employee. Once the emergency contact has been notified, any further action is up to them, not the company. If the employee has not given an emergency contact, that's typically a sign that they don't want the company in their personal business, so the company has no responsibility to follow up.
4. A concerned employer may encourage some other employees that could be considered "friends" or "good personal relationship" to reach out. But this is pretty much all they can do.
5. Many companies have an "abandonment" clause. Example "if you don't show up 3 days in a row without notification, we assume that you have abandoned the job". This legally terminates the employment.

Comment: Which jurisdiction do you assume for 5.? I have never heard of a clause like this and I'm not sure it would even be legal in say Germany.

Answer (score 3):

For the vast majority of workplaces it's not going to happen that way - there might be text messages or calls to inquire as to why you haven't turned up but it's unlikely to transition into things like welfare checks. The protocols around this sort of thing would be more likely disciplinary protocols rather than well being ones. Not unless work was aware of a reason they might be vulnerable - and even then it's more likely to be an informal exception rather than a defined process.

Where that *might* occur is where the person's job might be a reason for them to have come to harm - say a detective isn't turning up they might be concerned about a criminal or suspect having acted against them. But that's going to rely on having your character working in a very small subset of the workforce.

What's more likely in "normal" jobs would be a colleague who was friendly with them thinking that this was unlike them to no-call - no-show and go round to check on them as an individual.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly depends on country and culture. At any of the organizations I've worked at, mostly in IT, an unexplained absence would likely warrant a text message, **MAYBE** a phone call if there was an urgent issue pending that person's attention, but I don't think anyone would call the police to check on them until much later.

2nd day missed - I imagine HR would be asked about it and perhaps they would reach out to the person's emergency contact on file to try and reach them

That emergency contact would likely be the one that discovers the body; I can't imagine the workplace / HR actually sending police or an ambulance to look for someone. But that's in the US.

If they can't reach an emergency contact, I think it's *possible* but unlikely they'd escalate to the police to check on them after a 3rd missed day. After a few missed unexplained absences someone's job may very well be over in the US though without a good explanation.